# Testing android with FitNesse error: "Could not invoke constructor for .." & "The instance ... does not exist"

Tags: android, testing, fitnesse

I am trying to figure out how FitNesse works and didn't succeed to run successfully a test.
Does anyone can help me what I am missing?

I have followed all steps from the book "Android Application Testing Guide" .
I have an android sample project TemperatureConverter and a test project TemperatureConverterTest.

Bellow is my FitNesse Wiki:

```
!contents -R2 -g -p -f -h
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!path C:\User\Workspaces\android\FitNesse\fitnesse.jar
!path C:\User\Workspaces\android\TemperatureConverter\bin\classes\
!path C:\User\Workspaces\android\TemperatureConverterTest\bin\classes\ 

!|import                                   |
|com.example.aatg.tc.test.fitnesse.fixture|

!define COLLAPSE_SETUP {true}
!define COLLAPSE_TEARDOWN {true}

!|TemperatureConverterCelsiusToFahrenheitFixture          |
|celsius|fahrenheit?                                      |
|0.0    |~= 32                                            |
|100.0  |212.0                                            |
|-1.0   |30.2                                             |
|-100.0 |-148.0                                           |
|32.0   |89.6                                             |
|-40.0  |-40.0                                            |
|-273.0 |~= -459.4                                        |
|-273   |~= -459.4                                        |
|-273   |~= -459                                          |
|-273   |~= -459.40000000000003                           |
|-273   |-459.40000000000003                              |
|-273   |-459.41 < _ < -459.40                            |
|-274.0 |Invalid temperature: -274.00C below absolute zero|
```

but when I run test I have the following errors:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is to check your classpath declarations.  The error you are getting indicates that FitNesse is not finding your classes.

Make sure you have a !path declaration in the parent page to the test and make sure it is defined correctly.

See http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.ClassPath for more information.

**Updated:**
Now I can see that you do have your !path statements in there.  I must have missed them before.  So a few more things to look at:

- Does your Fixture have a .class file in the right place?
- Does your fixture class have a constructor method that requires arguments?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, currently I am involved into another project and will be able to test it later.

Answer (score 1):

The !path statements in the parent suite page or test page should point to the path of the directory where the parent package containing your .class files is at, NOT necessarily to the child directory containing the class files themselves.  The rest of the directory structure is implied by the class path in the import table on the test page.

So, in your example, you have

- !path of `C:\User\Workspaces\android\TemperatureConverter\bin\classes\`
- import of `com.example.aatg.tc.test.fitnesse.fixture`

so you need to concatenate them to find the .class file location
    C:\User\Workspaces\android\TemperatureConverter\bin\classes\com\example\aatg\tc\test\fitnesse\fixture\TemperatureConverterCelsiusToFahrenheitFixture.class

**For *nix users**

- the !path should not contain C:\  it should be from the root of your
  file system with forward slashes
- `/Users/johndoe/myFitProject/target/test-classes`

This should be the system directory where your java project's compiled class directory tree is rooted... in other words, the location of the "com" folder which ultimately contains your .class files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it one day, as I postponed its investigation